# binary int* array to int equivalent

Tags: c, arrays

I am quite new to C programming and am wondering whether there is a method in a pre-existent library that can help me in this particular situation or whether I need to write my own method to achieve the desired results.

Essentially, I will have an int* array representing a binary number. For example:

```
|1|0|1|1|
```

Ideally, I would like 11 to be returned from this array.

Is there are method in C that takes an int* array and returns the int equivalent of the numbers stored in it? Or is this something I need to write

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to take a look around and see how to ask a proper question, to increase the chances to gave some good answers from the community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/tour. For example, could you please show your efforts and paste a snippet of your code?

Comment: (Regarding the example, I think using decimal digits below 2 where binary digits are involved nearly as harmful as using keys that are valid as ordinals in sorting examples.)

Comment: `int*` is a type *pointing* to `int` not an `int`-array type.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you will need to write yourself.
Since there are no common real life use cases for representing numbers this way, the C standard library has no function to handle it.

However, this is a good exercise for learning about bit shifts.
Read up on `<<` and `>>` operators.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must do it by yourself. With << operator.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t u8_from_ubits(uint8_t* bits)
{
    int i;
    uint8_t num = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        num |= bits[7-i] << i; //8-1=7
    return num;
}

uint8_t bits[8] = {
    0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1
};

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",u8_from_ubits(bits));
    return 0;
}
```

For more bit count just change bit number in function